# Como atualizar mais de um registro em uma tabela usando FOR, a partir de "id" vindo de um array?

Tags: php, array, for

Olá.
Tenho uma *view* com uma *table* listando registro de **uma tabela de ordem de serviço**, na frente de cada registro tenho um checkbox para selecionar Ordens de Serviço aleatórias e fazer um agrupamento para faturar em uma única cobrança ou gerar uma NF.

`<input type="checkbox" name="id_ordem[]" value="<?php echo $ordem_servico->ordem_servico_id; ?>">`

Este é o input que recebe as seleções.

Estou enviando um array com os itens selecionados via POST para um *controller*

Assim estou recebendo em meu *controller* o POST.

```
        //recebendo os dados do POST lá do index de O.S
        $dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

        //Verficando se a variável $dados não está vazia
        if (!empty($dados['id_ordem'])) {

        //O comando implode, transforma um array em string
        $valor = implode(", ", $dados['id_ordem']);
            
        //pega só o valor dentro do array sem transformar em string
        $valor2 = ($dados['id_ordem']);
            
        //contando a quantidade de itens dentro da array
        $qty_array = count($valor2);
```

Estou recebendo o array corretamente.

Se eu selecionar duas ordens de serviço, vou receber dois id, perfeito até aqui. A minha dúvida vem a partir de agora:
Preciso alterar o valor do campo `ordem_servico_ativa`, por exemplo, de 2 para 6, em cada um dos registros selecionados.

Eu cheguei até aqui:

```
        //laço de repetição para pegar as ordens de serviço e alterar o status dela
        for ($i = 0; $i < $qty_array; $i++) {

        $data = array(
        'ordem_servico_ativa' => 6,
                      
        );

        $data['ordem_servico_usuario_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $this->core_model->update('ordens_servicos', $data, array('ordem_servico_id' => **POPULAR ID**));
                    
        }
```

Nesta última linha eu preciso popular o **ID** com o id vindo do array. Repetindo o processo na quantidade de seleções feitas.

Em resumo minha dúvida é:
Como fazer alterações de mais de um registro na tabela com id vindo de um array, usando laço de repetição?

Fico imensamente grato a todos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Olá algumas horas depois da pergunta e algumas tentativas, encontrei a solução e posto aqui, a título de curiosidade, ou talvez seja útil para mais alguém.

Eu comentei a solução no próprio código.

```
        //recebendo os dados do POST lá do index de O.S
        $dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

        //Verficando se a variável $dados não está vazia
        if (!empty($dados['id_ordem'])) {
           
        //pega só o valor dentro do array sem transformar em string
        $valor = ($dados['id_ordem']);
            
        //contando a quantidade de itens dentro da array
        $qty_array = count($valor);
            
        //pegando array da variável $valor, pois a variável $dados_desc receberá os dados do array decrementados a cada laço do FOR
        $dados_desc = $valor;
            

         
        //laço de repetição para pegar as ordens de serviço e alterar o status dela
        for ($i = 0; $i < $qty_array; $i++) {

        $data = array(
        'ordem_servico_ativa' => 6,
                        
        );
        //Atribuindo à variável, o id existente na primeira posição do array
        $id = ($dados_desc['0']);

        $data['ordem_servico_usuario_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        //Atualizando tabela com os dados necessários
        $this->core_model->update('ordens_servicos', $data, array('ordem_servico_id' => $id));
                    
        //Aqui o pulo do gato. Faço a exclusão da primeira posição do array [0], 
        //isso faz com que no próximo laço o registro da posição [1] ocupe o espaço [0]
        array_shift($dados_desc);
                    
        //Assim ele vai fazer os laços de acordo com a quantidade de "ID's" dentro do array,
        //e a variável $id será populada sempre com a posição [0], pois ela será elimidada a 
        //cada laço recebendo a próxima posição
                    
        }
```

Obrigado a todos, que de alguma forma já me ajudaram com suas dúvidas sanadas aqui na comunidade.

Comment: Você não precisa usar o array_shift, basta usar `$id = ($dados_desc[$i]);`, para pegar o valor na posição correta conforme o loop.

Comment: Sim Benilson, verdade, melhora mesmo o código, mais otimizado. Obrigado, vou deixar ele assim.